# How to bind migrations with executable

Tags: mysql, database, go, database-migration

I have a Go project using [goose](https://github.com/pressly/goose) for Mysql migrations. I would like to bind the migrations to the package executable so that the executable can be deployed and used independently from any system, similar to JAR files in JAVA projects.

Is there an equivalent in Go to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to get a single file which can migrate database and work

1. Install

   ```
   go get -u github.com/pressly/goose/cmd/goose
   ```
2. Make app. I base it on example`main.go` and add `run` option. Suppose your project is located at `github.com/user/project`:

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "database/sql"
       "flag"
       "log"
       "os"

       "github.com/pressly/goose"

       // Init DB drivers. -- here I recommend remove unnecessary - but it's up to you
       _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
       _ "github.com/lib/pq"
       _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
       _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"

       // here our migrations will live  -- use your path 
       _ "github.com/user/project/migrations"
   )

   var (
       flags = flag.NewFlagSet("goose", flag.ExitOnError)
       dir   = flags.String("dir", ".", "directory with migration files")
   )

   func main() {
       flags.Usage = usage
       flags.Parse(os.Args[1:])

       args := flags.Args()

       //////
       if len(args) > 1 && args[0] == "run" {
          log.Printf("PROGRAM RUN\n")  //
          ..... 
          os.Exit(0)
       }


       if len(args) > 1 && args[0] == "create" {
           if err := goose.Run("create", nil, *dir, args[1:]...); err != nil {
               log.Fatalf("goose run: %v", err)
           }
           return
       }

       if len(args) < 3 {
           flags.Usage()
           return
       }

       if args[0] == "-h" || args[0] == "--help" {
           flags.Usage()
           return
       }

       driver, dbstring, command := args[0], args[1], args[2]

       switch driver {
       case "postgres", "mysql", "sqlite3", "redshift":
           if err := goose.SetDialect(driver); err != nil {
               log.Fatal(err)
           }
       default:
           log.Fatalf("%q driver not supported\n", driver)
       }

       switch dbstring {
       case "":
           log.Fatalf("-dbstring=%q not supported\n", dbstring)
       default:
       }

       if driver == "redshift" {
           driver = "postgres"
       }

       db, err := sql.Open(driver, dbstring)
       if err != nil {
           log.Fatalf("-dbstring=%q: %v\n", dbstring, err)
       }

       arguments := []string{}
       if len(args) > 3 {
           arguments = append(arguments, args[3:]...)
       }

       if err := goose.Run(command, db, *dir, arguments...); err != nil {
           log.Fatalf("goose run: %v", err)
       }
   }

   func usage() {
       log.Print(usagePrefix)
       flags.PrintDefaults()
       log.Print(usageCommands)
   }

   var (
       usagePrefix = `Usage: goose [OPTIONS] DRIVER DBSTRING COMMAND
   Drivers:
       postgres
       mysql
       sqlite3
       redshift
   Examples:
       goose sqlite3 ./foo.db status
       goose sqlite3 ./foo.db create init sql
       goose sqlite3 ./foo.db create add_some_column sql
       goose sqlite3 ./foo.db create fetch_user_data go
       goose sqlite3 ./foo.db up
       goose postgres "user=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable" status
       goose mysql "user:password@/dbname?parseTime=true" status
       goose redshift "postgres://user:password@qwerty.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/db"
   status
   Options:
   `

       usageCommands = `
   Commands:
       up                   Migrate the DB to the most recent version available
       up-to VERSION        Migrate the DB to a specific VERSION
       down                 Roll back the version by 1
       down-to VERSION      Roll back to a specific VERSION
       redo                 Re-run the latest migration
       status               Dump the migration status for the current DB
       version              Print the current version of the database
       create NAME [sql|go] Creates new migration file with next version
   `
   )
   ```
3. Create folder for migrations:

   ```
   mkdir migrations && cd migrations
   ```
4. Create first migrations. We will use `go`-style migrations:

   ```
   goose mysql "user:password@/dbname?parseTime=true" create init go
   ```

   You'll get a file `00001_init.go` with Go code. Migrations are baked in it as SQL-commands. Just edit them as you need.
5. Then go to the main folder and build the application:

   ```
   cd ..
   go build -v -o myapp *.go
   ```
6. You'll get a file `myapp` with all the migrations baked in it. To check move it to some other place, for example to `/tmp` folder, and run from there:

   ```
   ./myapp mysql "user:password@/dbname?parseTime=true" status
   ```
7. Run your app:

   ```
   ./myapp run
   ```

### Result

You have single file which can be used as a migration tool so as a working application itself. All the migration are buil-it. In source code they are stored in a subpackage `migrations` - so it's easy to edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Docker you may put folder to the image.

If not projects like https://github.com/rakyll/statik or https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata can help.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt suggestion. I'm not using Docker. Can you suggest how to use go-bindata incase of goose? I'm a bit lost with its documentation.

Comment: I looked at goose. It seems to be providing a convenient way to build migrations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using Goose, one option would be to write the migrations in Go instead of SQL. Based on the [Go migrations example](https://github.com/pressly/goose/tree/master/examples/go-migrations) in the Goose repo, when you build the `goose` binary here, it will bundle all the `*.go` ones into the binary.

This was the output after I built the example and removed all files except the binary itself. The Go-based migration was embedded:

```
2017/10/31 11:22:31     Applied At                  Migration
2017/10/31 11:22:31     =======================================
2017/10/31 11:22:31     Mon Jun 19 21:56:00 2017 -- 00002_rename_root.go
```

If you're looking to use SQL-based migrations but don't want to take on additional dependencies, you could embed your SQL-based migrations into `*.go` files as string constants, then, starting from the `go-migrations` example, add an init phase to `main.go` that writes them out to the current directory before proceeding.